# Search in a single column in Datatable

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have a Datatable with fields Name, Id number , Username, Position.

[image]

Then I have search field with a dropdown which has two fields as that of fields in datatable.
[image]
[image]

I enter the searchitem and select the option from dropdown which is columnname in which I want to search the entered text and display the result.
I tried `$(table).DataTable().column(columnname).search(searchtext).draw()` but it didn't worked.

Is this sample right? Or how can I search into single column in datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is not very clear. It looks as you are trying to implement client-side single-column search/filtering in Datatables. If true, I recommend [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html).

BTW, I don't see anything specific to AEM or HTL/Sightly in your question, will be removing those tags.

Comment: Thank You!! Your example helped me!!